# Double FOR in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with some employee, the date of creation and the person in charge.

```
Name   | Created       | responsible
Jose     2017-01-01      Pedro
Lorena   2017-03-01      Pedro
Ana      2016-01-12      Pedro
Luis     2015-01-23      Ana
```

I need to draw with an sql, for each year and responsible the number of creations

```
year   |   responsible   |    Creations
2017       Pedro                2
2016       Pedro                1
2015       Ana                  1
```

I understand that I should do a double loop for each year (extracted from the creation date) and responsible. And then the record sum for that year and responsible for putting it in the new field "Creations"

I do not know how to put all the pieces together at the same time, the query is bigger, but with that small example, to see the syntax and fit all the pieces, would be of great help.

Many thanks to whoever can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try group by:

```
select extract(year from created),responsible,count(1) 
from tablename 
group by responsible,extract(year from created)
```